# Relationship between kernel function and basis

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, soft-question

Is there any relationship between a kernel function and the concept of basis in a vector space?

For example does an equality like this

$$
g(x) = \int_{\Omega} \alpha(y) K(x,y)dy
$$

have anything to do with something like

$$
g(x) = \sum_{i}\alpha_iK_i(x)
$$
?

Is there any concept of "uncountable" basis maybe?

Comment: see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercer%27s_theorem

Comment: Given it's a *soft question*, can't you just summarize few keypoints in an answer?

Comment: The thing is my knowledge of this area is pretty shallow. Even if it's a soft question, I don't wanna possibly write nonsense as an answer. Hopefully, someone more knowledgeable will come along and provide those key points.